# MySQL SUM of field with conditon, IF(SUM(bill_1) IS NULL, '99', SUM(bill_1)) AS tot_bill_1

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join, sum, conditional-statements

I want SUM(tot_bill_1+tot_bill_2) AS total, but it's not work

```
SELECT *, 
IF(SUM(bill_1) IS NULL, '99', SUM(bill_1)) AS tot_bill_1, 
IF(SUM(bill_2) IS NULL, '10', SUM(bill_2)) AS tot_bill_2, 
SUM(tot_bill_1+tot_bill_2) AS total
FROM billing
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using subquery:

```
SELECT sum_bill1,
       sum_bill2,
       (sum_bill1 + sum_bill2) AS total
FROM
  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(bill1), 99) AS sum_bill1,
          COALESCE(sum(bill2), 10) AS sum_bill2
   FROM billings) t
```